# Display ACF image field inside foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom taxonomy for my custom post type.

Each term only needs to display its name (which works with `$term->name;`) and an image. For the image I am using ACF (as I usually do for custom fields on a page or post). It is set up and I can select an image when I add a new term in the dashboard, but how do I display it in a foreach loop? The usual `get_field()` isn't showing anything.

```
<ul class="taxonomy-terms">
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    ?>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term) { ?>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" />
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The issue being with `the_field('image');`

The image field is set to return the image url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add your taxonomy as a parameter when calling the image, try :

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image', $term); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's better to test the Image Field as you don't wan't to show an empty `<img>` tag.

Also please check that you didn't change the field name in the Image Field settings.

You can read about that here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/
And here :
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Let's hope this works,

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the current term of the loop as the second parameter of the ACF function:

```
<?php the_field('image', $term); ?>
```

See here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was trying all sorts of convoluted solutions.